# Changing PrintArea page size using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

When the `PrintArea` consumes more than 1 page, you can adjust the page size ratio in Page Break View via the dashed line in the picture below:

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the size ratio using VBA? I couldn't find any properties exposed by [`PageSetup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196103.aspx) that allows this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HPageBreaks.add` method to create a new page break in a given location. For example:

```
Sub PageBreaks()
    Dim shtSheet As Worksheet

    Set shtSheet = ActiveSheet

    shtSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=Range("A10")
End Sub
```